# Bundling a static library as a single archive

Tags: go, static-libraries, archive

I am working on a go library which I intend to distribute as a binary artifact. Now I am aware that there are different `-buildmode` options and `archive` should pretty much do that for me and go 1.7+'s `//go:binary-only-package` makes the trick official.

However, when I build my library the resulting archive (`*.a`) contains my library only, not any dependencies. I am in fact having a dependency which itself is binary only and comes as a statically linked archive itself (it's a C library which I am integrating with).

Using proper native code archives I am actually able to assemble such a fat archive using `ar` or `libtool` trickery - but these tools do not really work with my go artifacts.

Is there a way I can distribute a single `*.a` file or do I have to resort to packaging multiple archives into, say, a zip file which resembles the directory structure in `$GOPATH` and tell the my client's developers to just unzip that into their `$GOPATH` and be done with it?

Comment: Aren't you distributing a zip file anyway, with both pkg and src directories, with the latter containing your package documentation?

Comment: @TimCooper We will distribute something like this, but we would prefer if it was one archive so it's not immediately obvious what the dependencies are.

Comment: Go packages _always_ require a source file, even if it's only a `go:binary-only-package` stub. You can't package archives together if you want to work with the Go (creating an archive like this is only a minor obfuscation, what does it matter what the dependencies are?)

Comment: @JimB I do understand that, as can be seen from the first paragraph in my question.

Comment: @scravy: then I'm not sure what you're asking. As you also said, you can pack the archives together, but it no longer works with the standard Go build tools.